# WALinuxAgent on FreeBSD service not installing

Tags: azure, freebsd

I'm walking through [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-freebsd-create-upload-vhd/) guide to try and push my own freebsd VHD into Azure. I've made it to step 6, but when checking to see if the WALinuxAgent service is installed, it isn't.
I don't get any errors during previous steps.
The output of Running the command "waagent -version" returns
WALinuxAgent-2.1.6 running on freebsd 10.3
Python; 2.7.12

I'm a noob with FreeBSD and the WALinuxAgent and have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

added waagent_enable to rc.conf. All ok now.